# How to use bearer-only access type authentication for Keycloak for asp.net APIs?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak, bearer-token, keycloak-services

I have created a sample REST api and secured using Keycloak OpenID connect.  For the client I have selected *confidential* access type. When i run the application it will redirect to keycloak login page and authentication works good. but I want to avoid Login page by using *barer-only* access type.Please suggest how to use this approach.
Thanks in advance.